Executing contract function to change Contract state
i am trying to execute function that changing the state of the contract, currently i am testing it on my localhost hardhat node.
this is my function (in my contract)
    address owner;
    string[] public deployedCampaignsUuid;
    mapping(string => Campaign) campaigns;

    struct Campaign {
        string uuid;
        address owner;
        string campaignName;
        string campaignDescription;
        address[] contributorsKeys; 
        uint256 endDate;
        uint256 goalAmount;
        uint256 totalContributions;
        string campaignType;
        mapping(address => uint256) contributors;
    }

    function createCampaign(
        string memory uuid,
        string memory campaignName,
        string memory campaignDescription,
        uint256 endDate,
        uint256 goalAmount,
        string memory campaignType
    ) public {
        require(bytes(uuid).length > 0, "UUID is required");
        require(bytes(campaigns[uuid].uuid).length == 0, "This campaign UUID already exists");
        campaigns[uuid].uuid = uuid;
        campaigns[uuid].owner = msg.sender;
        campaigns[uuid].campaignName = campaignName;
        campaigns[uuid].campaignDescription = campaignDescription;
        campaigns[uuid].endDate = endDate;
        campaigns[uuid].goalAmount = goalAmount;
        campaigns[uuid].totalContributions = 0;
        campaigns[uuid].campaignType = campaignType;
        deployedCampaignsUuid.push(uuid);
        delete campaigns[uuid].contributorsKeys;
        emit CampaignCreated(uuid, msg.sender);
    }

When i am executing the function from the javascript i don't see any error and in fact i am seeing information on the hardhat localhost.
but after so when i am trying to retreive the new infromation that was stored by the UUID i am not getting any result, the state of the contract didn't change.
i am invoking from my Typescript this function
export const getCampaignFactoryContract = async () => {
    try {
        const provider = await new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.BLOCKCHAIN_URL);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner()
        const abi = await generateABI();
        const campaignFactoryContract = await new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);

        campaignFactoryContract.on("CampaignCreated", async (uuid: string, owner: string) => {
            console.log("New campaign created with the following parameters");
            console.log("Owner Wallet Address: ", owner);
            console.log("Campaign UUID: ", uuid);
        });

        campaignFactoryContract.on("Contribution", async (uuid: string, owner: string, amount: bigint, time:number) => {
            console.log("New Contribution");
            console.log("Contiruber: ", owner);
            console.log("Campaign UUID: ", uuid);
            console.log("Amount: ", amount);
            console.log("Time: ", time);
        });

        return campaignFactoryContract;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Failed to get blockchain factory contract ", e);
        return null;
    }
}

export const requestBlockchainForNewCampaign = async (
    uuid: string,
    campaignName: string,
    description: string,
    endDate: number,
    goalAmountInWei: bigint,
    campaignType: string,
) => {
    try {

        const service = await getCampaignFactoryContract();
        const providers = await getProviders()
        if (service && providers) {
            const signer = await providers?.getSigner()
            const unsignedTx = await service['createCampaign'].populateTransaction(
                uuid,
                campaignName,
                description,
                endDate,
                goalAmountInWei,
                campaignType,
            );
            const signedTx = await signer.signTransaction(unsignedTx);
            console.log("Transaction hash:", signedTx);
            return true
        } else {
            console.log("Failed to obtain campaign factory contract.");
            return false
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failed to request creation of new campaign ", error);
        return false
    }
}

i am using Ether js. i don't understand how i can sign those transaction to change the state of the contract.
also i am using Metamask as my wallet, user can "connect" their metamask to my site

The typescript that you’ve attached, is present in the frontend/client-side of your dApp?

The code is on my frontend
